# Display floating point by printf

Tags: assembly, floating-point, shared-libraries, printf

I have problem with display floating point value using printf.

I'm trying display result of some math function, but I always get 0.00.

Could you help me and tell what I'm doing wrong?

My GNU AS code:

```
.text
text: .ascii  "Function result: %4.2f \n"
.data
x: .float 2.0
one: .float 1.0
result: .float 0.0


format: .ascii "%f"


.global main

main:
push $x
push $format
call scanf


FINIT

FLDS x  

FMULS x     #x*x

FADDS one   

FSQRT       

FSUB one        

FSTS result

xor %eax, %eax


push $result
push $text

call printf


pushl $0
call exit
```

Comment: I am not familiar with the syntax of the specific assembler version you are using, but `push $result` passes the address of `result` to `printf` by putting in on the stack. You likely need to pass the value of `result` either by putting in on the stack or in a floating-point register, depending on the ABI. (In the latter case, simply deleting the `FSTS result` and `push $result` instructions might suffice.) Also, do you know whether the `.ascii` directive puts a null character at the end of the string? If not, you might need `.asciz` or need to add a null byte to the string another way.

Comment: (32-bit) `printf`, although we say `%f`, always expects a double-precision argument on the stack.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, I think I push a value because I use $ symbol, without this I would push address. I added null character to my string and dalete these instructions, but this doesn't help.

@Frank Kotler, I tried change declaration of `result` from float to double and then put it into stack, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the GNU assembler, `$` designates a literal value (a value that is encoded into the instruction). The value of a label is its address. So `$x`, `$format`, `$result`, and `$text` are the addresses of those labels; they are the addresses where you have the values you are labeling. `printf` does not use an address for `%f`. You must pass the value of the floating-point number, not its address. And, as Frank Kotler notes, you must pass it as a 64-bit `double`, not a 32-bit `float`, because C rules implicitly promote `float` arguments to `double` for variadic functions.

The easiest way to do this might be to insert `add $-8, %esp` before the `FSTS result` instruction and change the `FSTS result` instruction to `FSTL (%esp)` to store a 64-bit `double` to the stack.  (Or `FSTPL (%esp)` to pop the value from the floating-point stack instead of leaving it there.) Then delete the `push $result`.

These changes will allocate eight bytes on the stack (in the `add` instruction) and store the floating-point result to those eight bytes.

Also, I expect your code is responsible for cleaning up arguments passed to called routines: It should add eight to the stack pointer after calling `scanf` to pop the two arguments, and it should add twelve after calling `printf` to pop the new eight-byte argument and the four-byte address of the format string. Your program may work without these changes since you terminate the program by calling `exit`. However, it would not be possible to return from a routine with the `ret` instruction without cleaning up the stack.

### Supplement

The following code works at [ideone.com](http://ideone.com), using the second choice for Assembler (gcc-4.7.2):

```
.text
text: .asciz  "Function result: %4.2f \n"
.data
x: .float 2.0
one: .float 1.0
result: .float 0.0


format: .asciz "%f"


.global main

main:
push $x
push $format
call scanf
add $8, %esp

FINIT

FLDS x  

FMULS x     #x*x

FADDS one   

FSQRT       

FSUB one        
add $-8, %esp
FSTPL (%esp)

xor %eax, %eax


push $text

call printf
add $12, %esp


pushl $0
call exit
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It helps me understand what was wrong. I correct my program as you said, but it still can't display result. Actually it looks this http://pastebin.com/qeUaYYqx
You are right about cleaning stack, without calling exit I got SeqFault