# Read and display float or double number in assembly in Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: visual-c++, assembly, floating-point, x86, masm

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 to learn inline assembly programming. I have read a lot of posts on stackoverflow including the most relevant one [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629805/display-floating-point-by-printf), but after I tried the methods the result is still 0.0000. I used the float first and store the value to fpu but the reuslt is the same and tried passing value to eax and still no help.

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char input1[] = "Enter number: \n";
    char input_format[] = "%lf";
    double afloat;
    char output[] = "The number is: %lf";


_asm {
    lea eax, input1
    push eax
    call printf_s
    add esp, 4

    lea eax, input_format
    push eax
    lea eax, afloat
    push eax
    call scanf_s
    add esp, 8

    sub esp, 8
    fstp [esp]

    lea eax, output
    push eax
    call printf
    add esp, 12

}
return 0;
}
```

The result:[image: result]

Comment: `afloat` is a really confusing name for a variable of type `double` (not `float`).

Comment: Your code is completely lacking in comments, which is almost never a good idea. I see that you've (apparently) tried to break it up into logical blocks, but each of those blocks should probably have a comment associated with it describing the general purpose of the code in that block. I probably comment my own code *too* extensively, but it is a good habit to get into, especially when you're writing assembly, which is anything but self-documenting! Strategic comments also might help you see strange things like `add esp, 8`, followed immediately by `sub esp, 8`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to print the wrong value. In fact, the code *should* just be causing nonsense to be printed to the terminal. You got quite lucky that you see `0.0`. Let's look specifically at the part of the code that *retrieves* the floating point value, which is your call to `scanf_s`:

```
lea eax, input_format
push eax
lea eax, afloat
push eax
call scanf_s
add esp, 8

sub esp, 8
fstp [esp]
```

First of all, I don't see any logic in adding 8 to your stack pointer (`esp`) and then immediately subtracting 8 from the stack pointer. Performing these two operations back-to-back just cancel each other out. As such, these two instructions can be deleted.

Second, you are pushing the arguments on the stack in the wrong order. The cdecl calling convention (used by the CRT functions, including `printf_s` and `scanf_s`) passes argument in *reverse order*, from right to left. Therefore, to call `scanf_s`, you would first push the address of the floating-point value into which the input should be stored, and then push the address of the format control string buffer. Your code is wrong, because it pushes the arguments from left to right. You get lucky with `printf_s`, because you're only passing one argument, but because you're passing two arguments to `scanf_s`, bad things happen.

The third problem is that you appear to be assuming that `scanf_s` returns the output directly.

If it did, and you had requested a floating point value, you would be correct that the `cdecl` calling convention would have it returning that value at the top of the floating-point stack, in `FP(0)`, and thus you would be correctly popping that value and storing it in a memory location (`fstp [esp]`).

While `scanf_s` *does* return a value (an integer value indicating the number of fields that were successfully converted and assigned), it does not return the value from the standard input stream. There is, in fact, no way that it could do this, since it supports arbitrary types of inputs. This is why it uses a pointer to a memory location to store the value. You probably knew this already, since you arranged to pass that pointer as a parameter to the function.

Now, why did you get an output of `0.0` in the final call to `printf`? Because of the `fstp [esp]` instruction. This pops the top value off of the floating-point stack, and stores it in the memory address contained in `esp`. I have already pointed out that `scanf_s` does not place any value(s) on the floating-point stack, so technically, it contains meaningless/garbage data. But in your case, you were lucky enough that `FP(0)` actually contained `0.0`, so that is what got printed. Why does `FP(0)` contain `0.0`? I'm guessing because this is a debug build that you're running, and the CRT is zeroing the stack. Or maybe because that's what `FSTP` pops off the stack when the stack is empty. I don't know, and I don't see that documented anywhere. But it doesn't really matter what happens when you write incorrect code, because you should strive to only write *correct* code!

Here's what *correct* code might look like:

```
; Get address of 'input1' buffer, and push it onto the stack
; in preparation of a call to 'printf_s'. Then, make the call.
lea  eax, DWORD PTR [input1]
push eax
call printf_s
add  esp, 4     ; clean up the stack after calling 'printf_s'

; Call 'scanf_s' to retrieve the floating-point input.
; Note that in the __cdecl calling convention, arguments are always
; passed on the stack in *reverse* order!
lea  eax, DWORD PTR [afloat]
push eax
lea  eax, DWORD PTR [input_format]
push eax
call scanf_s
; (no need to clean up the stack here; we're about to reuse that space!)

; The 'scanf_s' function stored the floating-point value that the user entered
; in the 'afloat' variable. So, we need to load this value onto the top
; of the floating point stack in order to pass it to 'printf_s'
fld  QWORD PTR [afloat]
fstp QWORD PTR [esp]

; Get the address of the 'output' buffer and push it onto the stack,
; and then call 'printf_s'. Again, this is pushed last because
; __cdecl demands that arguments are passed right-to-left.
lea  eax, DWORD PTR [output]
push eax
call printf_s
add  esp, 12    ; clean up the stack after 'scanf_s' and 'printf_s'
```

Note that you could optimize this code further by deferring the stack cleanup after the initial call to `printf_s`. You can just wait and do the cleanup later at the end of the function. Functionally, this is equivalent, but an optimizing compiler will often choose to defer stack cleanup to produce more efficient code because it can interleave it within other time-consuming instructions.

Also note that you technically do not need the `DWORD PTR` directives that I've used in the code because the inline assembler (and MASM syntax in general) tries to read your mind and assemble the code that you meant to write. However, I like to write it to be explicit. It just means that the value you're loading is `DWORD`-sized (32 bits). All pointers on 32-bit x86 are 32 bits in size, as are `int` values and single-precision `float` values. `QWORD` means 64 bits, like an `__int64` value or a `double` value.

---

**Warning:** When I first tested this code in MSVC using inline assembly, I couldn't get it to run. It worked fine when assembled separately using MASM, but when written using inline assembly, I couldn't execute it without getting an "access violation" error. In fact, when I tried your original code, I got the same error. Initially, I couldn't figure out how you were able to get your code to run, either!

Finally, I was able to diagnose the problem: by default, my MSVC project had been configured to *dynamically* link to the C runtime (CRT) library. The implementation of `printf`/`printf_s` is apparently doing some type of debug check that is causing this code to fail. I still am not entirely sure what the purpose of this validation code is, or exactly how it works, but it appears to be checking a certain offset within the stack for a sentinel value. Anyway, when I switched to *statically* linking to the CRT, everything runs as expected.

At least, when I compiled the code as a "release" build. In a "debug" build, the compiler can't tell that you need floating-point support (since all the floating-point stuff is in the inline assembly, which it can't parse), so it fails to tell the linker to link in the floating-point support from the CRT. As a result, the application bombs as soon as you run it and try to use `scanf_s` with a floating-point value. There are various ways of fixing this, but the simplest way would be to simply explicitly initialize the `afloat` value (it doesn't matter what you initialize it to; `0.0` or any other value would work just fine).

I suppose you are statically linking the CRT and running a release build, which is why your original code was executing. In that case, the code I've shown will both execute and return the correct results. However, if you're trying to learn assembly language, **I strongly recommend avoiding inline assembly and writing functions directly in MASM**. This is supported from within the Visual Studio environment, too; for setup instructions, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078021/how-to-enable-assembly-language-support-in-visual-studio-2013) (same for all versions).

Comment: Haha, I hadn't even noticed that the OP was pushing args in the wrong order.  But the OP's `add esp, 8`  / `sub esp, 8` does make sense if you read it like un-optimized compiler output (or un-optimized human output?).  Totally agree it's bogus and not something a human should leave or put in their code, but I wouldn't say "I don't see any logic" in it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you used a debugger to look at registers / memory?

`fstp [esp]` is extremely suspicious, because ST0 should be empty at that point.  scanf returns an integer, and the calling convention requires the x87 stack to be empty on call/return, except for FP return values.

I forget what happens when you FST while the x87 stack is empty.  If you get zero, that would explain it, since this is what you're passing to printf.

---

`add esp, 8` / `sub esp, 8` is completely redundant.  There's no point in doing that.  You can just take it out.  (Or comment it out but leave it there as a reminder that you've optimized by reusing the arg space on the stack instead of popping it and pushing new stuff.)

---

**Since `scanf` writes the `double` at the address you passed, you could avoid copying it by getting it to write it near the bottom of the stack**, and then adjust ESP to right below it.  Push a format string and you're ready to call printf, with the `double` already where it needs to be on the stack as the second arg.

```
sub   esp, 8       ; reserve 8 bytes for storing a `double` on the stack
push  esp          ; push a pointer to the bottom of that 16B we just reserved
push  OFFSET input_format    ; (only works if it's in static storage, but it's a string constant so you should have done that instead of initializing a non-const array with a literal inside `main`.)
call  scanf        ; scanf("%lf", ESP_before_we_pushed_args)
add   esp, 8
; TODO: check return value and handle error

; esp now points at the double stored by scanf
push  OFFSET output_format
call  printf
add   esp, 12     ; "pop" the args: format string and the double we made space for before the scanf call.
```

If the calling convention / ABI you're using requires that you make function calls with ESP 16B-aligned, you can't shorten it quite this much: you'll need an `lea eax, [esp+4]` / `push eax` or something instead of `push esp`, because the `double` can't be right above scanf's second arg but also *be* printf's second arg if both calls have the stack 16B-aligned.  So have scanf store the `double` at a higher address, and `add esp, 12` to reach it.

IDK if MSVC-style inline-asm guarantees any kind of stack alignment in the first place.  Inline-asm seems to make this problem more complicated in some ways than just writing the whole function in asm.

Comment: Inline assembly doesn't disrupt function-level stack alignment, for the entire function that contains the inline assembly. But it doesn't guarantee stack alignment for things that you do inside of the inline asm block. The truth is, calling functions from within inline assembly is always extremely fiddly and something that I try to avoid at all costs. In this case, strange things start happening when you try to call `printf` when dynamically linking to the CRT. I noodled about that a bit in my answer, but the upshot is inline asm is quite bad for learning asm!

Comment: @CodyGray: yeah, I've always been *extremely* leery of calling functions from inline asm, especially `static` functions.  Compilers are free to do inter-procedural optimizations on functions that aren't reachable from outside what they can see.  So an asm `call foo` might call a version of foo that clobbers `ebx`, because the compiler decided that would be best for this compilation unit.  (Probably unlikely in real code with MSVC, and I know that gcc names modified version of functions `foo.clone123` or `foo.constprop_455` and so on.)

Comment: I actually have no idea if that's unlikely in MSVC. I've never thought about it. Certainly, if you enable link-time code generation in a 32-bit build, MSVC frequently uses custom calling conventions even across compilands, so this could easily be a real problem. The only way to avoid it would either be by accident, or if the compiler actually parses the inline asm to see if you're calling functions from it. Since I don't think it does the latter, this is probably a good way to make things go boom. It doesn't do this with the CRT functions, though, so not a problem in this case.

Comment: @CodyGray: ah, so it just emits non-standard-ABI definitions under the usual symbol name?  (I don't think gcc does that, but I'm not sure it always uses a .clone... name.  Anyway yeah, that makes it extremely dangerous to call static functions from inline-asm, or link-time-optimized functions.  I remember pointing out these concerns in comments on a question about calling functions from GNU C inline-asm, which definitely doesn't parse the asm looking for symbol names.

Comment: Yes. But it only does it when you enable LTCG (aka whole-program optimization), so it's perfectly free to do that without any possible ABI violations.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the help and caveats offered. There are still problems I need to configure and fix, but after reading most float point operators on [this website](http://x86.renejeschke.de/) , I finally come up with a solution to read and display float point number with Microsoft Visual Studio. I am sorry for all the bad conventions I've used in this post and lack of comments, I will learn to program in a better style. Thanks again!

Here is my working code(different from original post since I want to use float point number there):

```
#include "stdafx.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
char input1[] = "Enter number: \n";
char input_format[] = "%f";
char output_format[] = "%.2f\n"; //for better ouput 
float afloat;
char output[] = "The number is:";


_asm {
    lea eax, input1
    push eax
    call printf_s
    add esp, 4

    call flushall; // flush all streams and clear all buffers
    mov afloat, 0; // give the variable afloat a default
    lea eax, afloat;
    push eax;
    lea eax, input_format; // read the floating number user inputs
    push eax;
    call scanf_s;
    add esp, 8;

   //leave space for more operations.

    lea eax, output;
    push eax;
    call printf; // print the output message
    add esp, 4;

    sub esp, 8; // reserve stack for a double in stack
    fld dword ptr afloat; // load float
    fstp qword ptr[esp]; // IMPORTANT: convert to double and store, because printf expects a double not a float 
    lea eax, output_format; // import the floating number format '%f'
    push eax;
    call printf; // print the variable afloat
    add esp, 12;


}
return 0;
}
```

The result looks like this:
[image]